# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method soapclient::_call()

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I am working on a SOAP service to  upload pictures and I get this error when I upload a picture with the webservice. I dont have too much experience with php and SOAP webservices so I will apreciate any help. I am using a php library call it [nusoap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). This is my code:

## server.php

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); //include required class for build nnusoap web service server

// Create server object
$server = new soap_server();

// configure  WSDL
$server->configureWSDL('Upload File', 'urn:uploadwsdl');

// Register the method to expose
$server->register('upload_file',                                 // method
array('file' => 'xsd:string','location' => 'xsd:string'),    // input parameters
array('return' => 'xsd:string'),                             // output parameters
'urn:uploadwsdl',                                            // namespace
'urn:uploadwsdl#upload_file',                                // soapaction
'rpc',                                                       // style
'encoded',                                                   // use
'Uploads files to the server'                                // documentation
);

// Define the method as a PHP function

function upload_file($encoded,$name) {
$location = "uploads\\".$name;                               // Mention where to upload the file
$current = file_get_contents($location);                     // Get the file content. This will create an empty file if the file does not exist     
$current = base64_decode($encoded);                          // Now decode the content which was sent by the client     
file_put_contents($location, $current);                      // Write the decoded content in the file mentioned at particular location      
if($name!="")
{
    return "File Uploaded successfully...";                      // Output success message                              
}
else        
{
    return "Please upload a file...";
}
}

// Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

## cliente.php

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); //include required class for build nnusoap web service server
$wsdl="http://{servidor}/WebServiceSOAP/server.php?wsdl";  // SOAP Server

if($_POST["submit"])
{
  $tmpfile = $_FILES["uploadfiles"]["tmp_name"];   // temp filename
  $filename = $_FILES["uploadfiles"]["name"];      // Original filename

  $handle = fopen($tmpfile, "r");                  // Open the temp file
  $contents = fread($handle, filesize($tmpfile));  // Read the temp file
  fclose($handle);                                 // Close the temp file

  $client=new soapclient($wsdl) or die("Error");   // Connect the SOAP server
  $response = $client->_call('upload_file',array($filename)) or die("Error");  //Send two inputs strings. {1} DECODED CONTENT {2} FILENAME
}   

//$client=new soapclient($wsdl) or die("Error");   // Connect the SOAP server
//$response = $client->__call('upload_file',array($decodeContent,$filename)) or die("Error");  //Send two inputs strings. {1} DECODED CONTENT {2} FILENAME

// Check if there is anny fault with Client connecting to Server
if($client->fault){
  echo "Fault {$client->faultcode} <br/>";
  echo "String {$client->faultstring} <br/>";
}
else{
print_r($response); // If success then print response coming from SOAP Server
}
<form name="name1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="uploadfiles"><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="uploadSubmit"><br />
</form>
```

I get this error when I press the upload button. This is my error_log:

## error_log"

```
[14-Apr-2018 22:44:57 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: submit in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 5
[14-Apr-2018 22:44:57 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: client in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 22
[14-Apr-2018 22:44:57 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 22
[14-Apr-2018 22:44:57 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: response in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 27
[14-Apr-2018 22:45:05 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method soapclient::_call() in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 3):

Just enable soap extension then the problem will be solved.

Open php.ini and change **;extension=soap** to **extension=soap**. Save changes and restart the Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

There Are few Problems In Your Code

1. on line 5 you have to use `isset` function for checking the submission.
2. The call Method has 2 Underscore (_) in front ([Magic function in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php))
3. There are Other Minor Bugs like $client will be not defined if not submited the request.

Comment: I use 2 underscore and same error:
[14-Apr-2018 23:54:34 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method soapclient::__call() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 15

Comment: `__call` is directly is deprecated instead you have to use `__soapCall` method. Specified in the [Official Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php)

Comment: I get same error.....[15-Apr-2018 00:05:35 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method soapclient::__soapCall() in /home/XXXX/public_html/WebServiceSOAP/client.php on line 17